# Table To Elastic Search - Create/Update

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a table with size of 50GB. I want to move the table to elastic search for faster search. Currently it takes more minutes even to run a count(1) query.

Is there is open source project which does this, so that we can use it for faster searching of results? Also whenever there is a considerable updates in the table need to push the changes to elastic search

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: I am assuming that you have an SQL table. You may use Logstash's JDBC Plugin to import these data https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html into Elasticsearch. If the lines are getting updated a "date" column is updated you may use :sql_last_value to get only the newly updated lines. To be able to update an entry, you may want to use the same document id also in Elasticsearch. You can take a look at this elastic blog https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-keep-elasticsearch-synchronized-with-a-relational-database-using-logstash

Comment: @Briomkez i have MySQL table. Any opensource UI for elastic search. Not an application i have just a DB want to lookup for the search basically

Comment: Hi, this Logstash JDBC Input Plugin is the tool to index your MySQL table into Elasticsearch. When the data is indexed in Elasticsearch, you can use Kibana (GUI) to query your data. You cannot use Elasticsearch to query your MySQL table directly.

Comment: @Briomkez Great...Can you please one good link to do that?

Comment: Hi.. have you already opened the link to the blog.elastic.co post I sent in the previous comment? The whole process is well-described.